# opinion on my method for a multi language site

Tags: php, coding-style, internationalization, multilingual

i'm working on my own way of handling a bilingual site. my method should allow proper search engine indexing and will keep everything on one page without external files.

one function would handle which content to display:

```
<?
    function l($en, $fr){
        echo ($_GET['lang'] === 'fr') ? $fr : $en ;
    }
?>
```

then the appropriate text will display according to language in URL (/?lang=en)

```
<h1><? l('welcome!', 'bienvenue!') ?></h1>
```

for an image this is my solution:

```
<img src="<? l('hi-en.png', 'hi-fr.png')?>" width="100" height="20">
```

can anyone name drawbacks to this method if used? is it unusual to have a single function handle language for pages which would include all language content?

Comment: I was just reading about how the framework [Kohana](http://kohanaframework.org/) utilizes [i18n](http://blog.mixu.net/2010/11/11/kohana-3-i18n-tutorial/), could be a help to you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general idea of using a singleton or global function like your `l` function is very common. You're definitely on the right track!

Your method does have some drawbacks, though:

- If you have the same text or image that appears in numerous places in the code, you need to maintain the translation in *every* place.
- Updating or correcting a translation requires wading through code, which is very difficult for inexperienced coders or non-coders (say, if you have a translator helping you).
- If you were ever to add a new language, you would have to modify *every source file*, which would be excruciating. This may be unlikely, but if it ever happened, you'd be rather cross with yourself.

A more typical solution is to have the translations located in a separate file, either as a simple hash or as a structured data format like XML, and then your `l` function would just look like `l('welcome')`; the parameter is a key, and `l` will look up the correct translation in the given language from the separate file.